# How to assign verts to bones (2.79(

Tags: edit-mode

I want to assign this vert to this bone [image: these are the things i want to be able to join]
When i try weight painting it just isnt as accurate

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a vertex to a bone must be done by first assigning that vertex to a *vertex group*. This vertex group must have the same name as the bone which will influence the vertex you want affected. If your mesh doesn't already have a vertex group with the name of this bone, you will need to create one. With the mesh selected that contains the vertex you want controlled, go to the *Object Data* tab in the Properties Panel, and under the Vertex Groups section, click the plus sign to add a new vertex group and give it *the same name as the bone you want to influence your vertex*. Now, in Edit Mode, select the vertex you want controlled and in the Vertex Group section, press the **Assign** button. If your mesh already has an armature modifier on it, then moving the bone in Pose Mode should move the vertex.

[image]

If it happens that your mesh *does* already have a vertex group with the same name as the bone you want to influence this vertex, then *don't* create a new one. Instead, go into Edit Mode, select that vertex group in the *Vertex Group* section, select the vertex you want to add to this group, and click **Assign**.

Once assigned, the weight of this vertex can be tweaked if it is too low or high by rolling out the Properties Shelf (<kbd>n</kbd> key) and looking for the *Vertex Weights* section. Listed underneath will be all the vertex groups this single selected vertex belongs to, along with the weights, which can be edited here.

[image]